# Firebird Embedded for web?

Tags: web-applications, firebird

I am evaluating some database options for a Web project. I wonder if the version of Firebird Embedded is stable for this type of development (Web).

I was thinking about the Firebird server version, but I would not like the end user having a problem with the installation of the server, since there was another instance running when I tried to install it.

Both on SQL Server and MySql Server you can install multiple instance with different names.
The database will be running lots of transactions per day(possibly 16k – 20k transactions per day).

The final idea is that the end user will be able to purchase and install the product hassle free.

I use Asp.Net

Comment: Why would you want to use an embedded server for a webapplication?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use Firebird 2.5 for ASP.NET application, there's no problem with that. Just make sure you include 64bit `fbembed.dll` on 64bit system (or vice versa).